# PHP if file exists, always show that exists

Tags: file, echo, exists

I have database columns attach1 and attach2.
I need to show files (pdf) from those columns, but only if they exist in directory www.domain.com/uploads. 
Attach1 contains real file but attach2 does not.

I tried something like this:

```
<?php
$file = $row['attach'];
$exists = file_exists('uploads/'.$file.''); 
if ($exists) {
  echo $file;
}
if (!$exists) {
  echo 'No file1';
}      
?>

<?php
$file2 = $row['attach2'];
$exists = file_exists('uploads/'.$file2.''); 
if ($exists) {
  echo $file2;
}
if (!$exists) {
  echo 'No file2';
}      
?>
```

But everytime it echoes me back, that file exists, even when attach2 contains nothing. Why?

Comment: Not to your question, but there are a number of pointless things in your code sample. You don't need to concatenate an ampty string onto the end of the filename. you don't need to save the result of `file_exists` in a variable. You can use `else` to simplify your conditionals.

Comment: Did you try to `echo $file2` and make sure it's not empty? If it is, you'd be checking `file_exists('/uploads')`, which is of course `TRUE`.

Comment: try this 'if(isset($file)'

Comment: Yes I'm sure its empty. Ok if I'm checking the directory, how can I check concrete file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your filename is empty, then you are passing only the directory name to `file_exists`. Directories are files too. And I reckon the directory does actually exist. It is not lying to you.

You can either check that the filename from the database is not empty, or you can pass the whole string to the function `is_dir` to see if it is a directory. I assume you only want regular files.

That would look something like this:

```
 <?php
 $file = $row['attach'];
 $exists = file_exists('uploads/'.$file.'') && !is_dir('uploads/'.$file.''); 
 if ($exists) {
   echo $file;
 } else {
   echo 'No file1';
 }      
 ?>
```

I changed the `if` statement to use an `else` clause. It is equivalent to using a second `if` like you did.

Comment: How would I do that? Please.

Comment: Which part? `is_dir`?